# Dirac operator with torsion

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, dirac-equation, spinors

On a spin manifold $M$, (in local coordinates) the Dirac operator $D_M$ is of the form $$-i\gamma^{\mu}(\partial_{\mu}-\frac{1}{4}\tilde{\Gamma}^b_{\mu a}\gamma^a\gamma_b),$$
where the (torsion-free) Levi-Civita connection is lifted to the spinor bundle $S\rightarrow M$.

I am looking for the case where we lift an affine connection (which is not necessarily torsion-free) to the spinor bundle. This would define a spin connection, and associated Dirac operator, with torsion.

How do I obtain this in local coordinates? In particular, any references discussing this in details would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: See Equation 11.65 of Göckeler and Schücker's Differential Geometry, Gauge Theories, and Gravity (1989). Also Appendix C of Doran and Lasenby's Gravity, Gauge Theories, and Geometric Algebra (2004).